# Find $\int_0^4(g\circ f\circ g)(x)\mathrm{d}x$ where $f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x+\sqrt{x^2+1/27}}+\sqrt[3]{x-\sqrt{x^2+1/27}}$, $g(x)=x^3+x+1$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, functions, definite-integrals

> Let $$f(x)=\sqrt[3]{x+\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{27}}}+\sqrt[3]{x-\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{27}}}$$
> and
> $$g(x)=x^3+x+1$$
> then, find $$\int_0^4(g\circ f\circ g)(x) \mathrm dx$$

**My attempt:**

Let $\displaystyle h(x)=\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{27}}$
$$(g\circ f)(x)=2x+3((2x)(x^2-[h(x)]^2))^{1/3}+(x+h(x))^{1/3}+(x-h(x))^{1/3}+1$$

Is finding $(g\circ f \circ g)(x)$ in term of $x$ necessary? Because it is quite a work to do.

Comment: So... what is your question? What part are you stuck at?

Comment: @an4s Is finding $(g\circ f \circ g)(x)$ in term of $x$ necessary?

Comment: Hint: $$f(x) = 2\sqrt3 x$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a nice problem.

---

$$f(x)=\underbrace{\sqrt[3]{x+\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{27}}}}_{a}+\underbrace{\sqrt[3]{x-\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{27}}}}_b$$

Now note that from the identity $(a+b)^3=a^3+b^3+3ab(a+b)$, and using $ab=-\dfrac{1}3$,

we have:

$$(f(x))^3=2x-f(x) \implies (f(x))^3+f(x)=2x $$

And from $g(x)=x^3+x+1$ , we have $$g(f(x))=(f(x))^3+f(x)+1=2x+1$$

Therefore $$g(f(g(x))=2g(x)+1=2x^3+2x+3$$

So all you have got is $$\int_0^4 (2x^3+2x+3)\mathrm{d}x$$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $f^{-1}(x) = \dfrac{x^3+x}{2}\\$

$\therefore g(x) = 2f^{-1}(x)+1\\$

$\therefore g(f(g(x))) = 2f^{-1}(f(g(x)))+1\\$

and I'm sure you know $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x \\$

$\therefore g(f(g(x))) = 2g(x)+1\\$

$$\therefore \int_0^4g(f(g(x)))dx = \int_0^4(2g(x)+1)dx = \int_0^4(2x^3+2x+3)dx\\$$